# for some reason the str keyword is still printing a list

Tags: python, string, list

```
import random
import pickle
alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
up_alphabets = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
special_chars = ['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','~','+','-','_','?']
def password(description):
    password = str()
    times = 0
    ten = 10
    k = list()
    global works
    works = False
    works1 = False
    works2 = False
    works3 = False
    n = list()
    for l in range(ten):
        o = random.randint(0,9)
        o = str(o)
        k.append(o)
    for l in range(ten):
        choice = random.randint(0,2)
        if choice == 0:
            works = True 
            password += k[times]
            times += 1
            password = str(password) 
        if choice == 1:
            up_low_choice = random.randint(0,1)
            if up_low_choice == 0:
                works1 = True
                alpha_choice = random.choice(alphabets)
                password += alpha_choice
                password = str(password) 
            if up_low_choice == 1:
                works2 = True
                alpha_choicee = random.choice(up_alphabets)
                password += alpha_choicee
                password = str(password) 
            times += 1        
        if choice == 2:
             works3 = True
             special_choice = random.choice(special_chars)
             password += special_choice
             times += 1
             password = str(password) 
    if works == False:
        password = list(password)
        password.pop()
        works = True 
        password += k[times]
        times += 1
        password = str(password) 
    if works1 == False:
        password = list(password)
        password.pop()
        works1 = True
        alpha_choice = random.choice(alphabets)
        password += alpha_choice
        password = str(password) 
    if works2 == False:
        password = list(password)
        password.pop()
        works2 = True
        alpha_choicee = random.choice(up_alphabets)
        password += alpha_choicee
        password = str(password) 
    if works3 == False:
        password = list(password)
        password.pop()
        works3 = True
        special_choice = random.choice(special_chars)
        password += special_choice
        password = str(password) 
    password = str(password) 
    print(str(password))
```

this is my code

it is a simple passoword generator
but when i run it it sometimes prints a string
and sometimes a list please help
i tried looking for any print commands that i left but there is only one print command at the end
the code is in progress but i need help for the time being
thanks in advance

####################################################################################################

Comment: sorry for unclearity but i am new to coding so plz help

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: You posted over 60 lines of code without trying to isolate the problem, and you haven't tried tracing the values yet.  This is not yet ready for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you are getting list so at the end you can add check for this and convert it to string check below code:

Add this code before last line of your code

```
try:
    password = eval(password)
    if type(password) is list:
        password = "".join(password)
        print("password is list")
except Exception:
    pass
```

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i wanted and sorry for making my code overcomplicated i am only 12 so my coding is not that strong

Comment: Then please be aware that a responsible programmer will not use `eval` in situations like this. Please read the canonical "[Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)".

Answer (score 1):

I think you over complicated your code. One big thing you're missing out on is there is a module called string which will help you gather all your characters. Basically the logic below is we combine a bunch of characters into a string. Then we will pick random chars from that string a random amount of times (8-16).

```
import string
from random import *
def generate():
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
    password = []
    for i in range(randint(8,16)):
        password.append(choice(characters))
    print(''.join(password))
generate()
```

List comprehension

```
import string
from random import *
def generate():
    characters = string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits
    password = [choice(characters) for i in range(randint(8,16))]
    print(''.join(password))
generate()
```

basically one liner

```
import string
from random import *
def x():return ''.join([choice(string.ascii_letters + string.punctuation  + string.digits) for i in range(randint(8,16))])
```

Comment: i know but i want to make it customizable and make it so it can save the passwords in a file so we can find it later

Comment: What do you mean by customizable? Like you want every pwd to be unique?